# how to accept values from users and store it in 2D array in Dart

Tags: dart

can anyone tell me how to accept values from users and store it in a 2D array in Dart

```
  print('enter the limit');
  var limit = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  List<List<int>> lisst =[];
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
      
    }
  }
}
```

i am stuck in it plz help

Comment: Can you try provide a more precise description of what your input is and what result you expect to generate? How should the 2D data structure look for a given input?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you edit the question and add what does 'stuck' mean? How to assign a value to one item in the array?